# Parsec: Handling Overlapping Parsers

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm really new to parsing in Haskell, but it's mostly making sense.

I'm working on building a Templating program mostly to learn parsing better; templates can interpolate values in via `{{ value }}` notation.

Here's my current parser,

```
data Template a = Template [Either String a]
data Directive = Directive String

templateFromFile :: FilePath -> IO (Either ParseError (Template Directive))
templateFromFile = parseFromFile templateParser

templateParser :: Parser (Template Directive)
templateParser = do
  tmp <- template
  eof
  return tmp

template :: Parser (Template Directive)
template = Template <$> many (dir <|> txt)
    where
      dir = Right <$> directive
      txt = Left <$> many1 (anyChar <* notFollowedBy directive)

directive :: Parser Directive
directive = do
  _ <- string "{{"
  txt <- manyTill anyChar (string "}}")
  return $ Directive txt
```

Then I run it on a file something like this:

```
{{ value }}

This is normal Text

{{ expression }}
```

When I run this using `templateFromFile "./template.txt"` I get the error:

```
Left "./template.txt" (line 5, column 17):
unexpected Directive " expression "
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

My basic understanding is that `many1 (anyChar <* notFollowedBy directive)`
should grab all of the characters up until the start of the next directive, then should fail and return the list of characters up till that point; then
it should fall back to the previous `many` and should try parsing `dir` again and should succeed; clearly something else is happening though. I'm
having trouble figuring out how to parse things *between* other things when
the parsers mostly overlap.

I'd love some tips on how to structure this all more idiomatically, please let me know if I'm doing something in a silly way. Cheers! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.  First, in Parsec, if a parser consumes any input and then fails, that's an error.  So, when the parser:

```
anyChar <* notFollowedBy directive
```

fails (because the character *is* followed by a directive), it fails *after* `anyChar` has consumed input, and that generates an error immediately.  Therefore, the parser:

```
let p1 = many1 (anyChar <* notFollowedBy directive)
```

will never succeed if it runs into a directive.  For example:

```
parse p1 "" "okay"   -- works
parse p1 "" "oops {{}}"  -- will fail after consuming "oops "
```

You can fix this by inserting a `try` clause:

```
let p2 = many1 (try (anyChar <* notFollowedBy directive))
parse p2 "" "okay {{}}"
```

which yields `Right "okay"` and reveals the second problem.  Parser `p2` only consumes characters that aren't followed by a directive, so that excludes the space immediately before the directive, and you have no means in your parser to consume a character that *is* followed by a directive, so it gets stuck.

You actually want something like:

```
let p3 = many1 (notFollowedBy directive *> anyChar)
```

which first checks that, at the current position, we aren't looking at a directive before grabbing a character.  No `try` clause is needed because if this fails, it fails without consuming input.  (`notFollowedBy` never consumes input, as per the documentation.)

```
parse p3 "" "okay" -- returns Right "okay"
parse p3 "" "okay {{}}" -- return Right "okay "
parse p3 "" "{{fails}}"  -- correctly fails w/o consuming input
```

So, taking your original example with:

```
txt = Left <$> many1 (notFollowedBy directive *> anyChar)
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

[replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/)
is a library for doing search-and-replace with parsers. The
search-and-replace function is
[`streamEdit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:streamEdit),
which can find your `{{ value }}` patterns and then substitute in some other text.

`streamEdit` is built from a generalized version
of your `template` function called
[`sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap).

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Data.Char

input = unlines
    [ "{{ value }}"
    , ""
    , "This is normal Text"
    , ""
    , "{{ expression }}"
    ]

directive :: Parsec Void String String
directive = do
    _ <- string "{{"
    txt <- manyTill anySingle (string "}}")
    return  txt

editor k = fmap toUpper k

streamEdit directive editor input
```

```hs
 VALUE 

This is normal Text

 EXPRESSION
```

Answer (score 0):

```
many1 (anyChar <* notFollowedBy directive)
```

This parses only characters not followed by a directive.

```
{{ value }}

This is normal Text

{{ expression }}
```

When parsing the text in the middle, it will stop at the last `t`, leaving the newline before the directive unconsumed (because it's, well, a character followed by a directive), so the next iteration, you try to parse a directive and you fail. Then you retry `txt` on that newline, the parser expects it not to be followed by a directive, but it finds one, hence the error.

Comment: Makes sense ; how can I best fix it to do what I expect?

Comment: `txt = many1 (notFollowedBy directive *> anyChar)` is the easiest fix, though it runs `directive` twice per directive.